# User forgot password alternative approach in spring

Tags: java, spring-security

I wanted to allow having a security question for users. I am using Spring3 and was not sure if there exists a standard way of doing this. Can anyone point me to such standard it at all it exists?

Comment: From a security point of view, security questions are very problematic, because they are easily guessable.So be careful when using them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a standard that covers this, but I would recommend that you treat the security questions just like you would the password...

- Make sure that you turn autocomplete="off" so that the browser won't remember their answer
- Generate a salted hash for the answer (or you could reuse the one for their password)

  ```
  public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      // VERY important to use SecureRandom instead of just Random
      SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

      // Generate a 8 byte (64 bit) salt as recommended by RSA PKCS5
      byte[] salt = new byte[8];
      secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);

      return salt;
  }
  ```
- Encrypt the answer

  ```
  public static byte[] getEncryptedAnswer(String answer, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(answer.toCharArray(), salt, 20000, 160);

      SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

      return secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
  }
  ```

Store both the salted hash and the encrypted answer.  At this point you're pretty much using the answer to this question just like a password.

---

Now with all that said, I have to agree with jHilscher... Too many of these security questions are predictable or easy to guess.  Favorite color, year they graduated, etc...  I never answer these questions with the correct information.  I recommend that you find a different way to reset the password when needed.